# TypeScript: Specify that an argument must contain a key matching another argument?

Tags: typescript, recursive-datastructures

I am working on a library that works with linked lists. At the moment, it is hard-coded to accept a list node type that contains a "next" field pointing to the next node, of the same type, but I would like it to be agnostic to the specific field names used for links--i.e., whether you happen to be dealing with list nodes connected by "prev" references or "next" references or "previous" or "pointer" or a numerical index (say, if you are using two-element arrays to simulate cons cells, for example), or whatever, with the user passing in a string indicating what the name of the list link field is.

Now, I can handle that in a type-unsafe way by just allowing the library to take objects conforming to a wide-open interface with an index signature to `any` (i.e., `interface ListNode { [key: string]: any }`), and then just trust the user to provide an object that actually does have the link key that they specified... but I would rather prefer to be able to actually *check* that the list nodes being provided to the library actually do have fields with the names that the library user claims they have. That's kind of the whole point of using TypeScript, after all.

I can get this far:

```
function doListStuff(head: { [ptr]: ??? }, ptr: string) { ... }
```

but I can't figure out what to put in for `???`--is there any way to do recursive anonymous types?

I have also tried this:

```
interface ListNode<Ptr extends string> {
   [Ptr]: ListNode<Ptr> | null;
}
```

But that gives me this list of errors:

> [ts] A computed property name in an interface must refer to an
>   expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
>   [ts] Cannot find name 'Ptr'.
>   [ts] A computed property name cannot reference a type parameter from its containing type.

So... is there any way to define an interface with computed property names?

Or any other way to actually do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to represent an object whose keys are some generic key-like type.  It looks like this:

```
type ListNode<P extends string> = { [K in P]: ListNode<P> | null };
```

(Note that the above definition doesn't seem to allow for any data, but you can add whatever other structure you want via [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) or the like).

Then your `doListStuff()` can be something like:

```
function doListStuff<P extends string>(head: ListNode<P>, ptr: P) {
    const next: ListNode<P> | null = head[ptr];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(next));
    if (next) doListStuff(next, ptr);
}
```

And you can see that it works:

```
doListStuff({ foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: null } } } }, "foo");
//{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":null}}}
//{"foo":{"foo":null}}
//{"foo":null}
//null;
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AOQPYBMIB4AKUIAewEAduglEgE5wkDmAfFALxQDeUA2gNJS1Q4AugC5YiFBmw4mAHygkArgBslUAL4BuAFBaAZgpIBjYHFQko6VPCQBlYAt27c+IqXKVgNegwAUACwgAQ3RRawlMXAYAGigwT1EcAEp2LSg0qEMzJHlCYFDxNAjpKDlFFRYoAODOOKpBbXSMrNQlCAA6JVQ6HwApGwB5ZDbqWjo4XRAfElzExIb08agpmYsrcTsHXWWiGNq5rTUdSzCNxx8OXVRUUQurm6hL6-YHu-llVTV1L7UYgCJH377AD0QLY-yuv2EYIBUPBqEhZSUamRWhB0IhsJhiJRaLhCPehxBiI0QA)